# Zoom Google Maps Android Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I'm doing my car tracking application. The problem is that when I zoomed in or out, the zoom restarts its position. And when I look at another part of the map, it returns me to my location. How can I solve that?

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   if(getApplicationContext()!=null){
        mLastLocation = location;

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CustomerMapActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}
```

Comment: dont move the camera in your onLocationChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, with every new location update, your are moving and zooming the camera so you need remove

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   if(getApplicationContext()!=null){
        mLastLocation = location;

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        // remove to stop frequent camera movement
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }
}
```

or alternatively, you can increase the location retrieval interval to give user some more time as

```
mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
```